# Error using bq mk command for creating empty table in BQ from GCS stored schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

I am trying to create an empty table in Bigquery using bq mk command

> bq mk --table V.abc --schema "gs://xyz/Schema/abc.schema"
> FATAL Flags positioning error: Flag '--schema' appears after final command line argument. Please reposition the flag.

Question -  Is it possible to create an empty table in BQ from GCS stored schema using bq mk command?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it directly at the moment, the schema JSON file needs to be locally readable when using bq mk (cf [this paragraph](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#using_a_json_schema_file)).

What you can do is using first gsutil cp to copy the file from GCS to your local shell, before removing it right after your `bq mk` command.

Comment: Thanks . I have used bq mk command with schema to create the table.

Comment: From GCS?!  ... Or from locally imported JSON?

Comment: locally imported json

Comment: Nice ! Glad to hear you solved the issue. Don't forget to mark the question as solved. It should help people with the same issue in the future.